# Multiple builds and tests from the same source code with declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to setup a continuous integration pipeline, where a single branch per source code repo is built in a few different flavors (release, debug etc) for a bunch of different devices and sent to target devices for testing. Finally a report needs to be made with status for each target device and under that each software for that target device.
It would be best if this could be kept mostly to the declarative pipeline code. Scripted pipeline if necessary. And multiple/different GUI-based jobs only as last resort.

I've tried a couple of different approaches, but nothing seems entirely right. Using the when conditionals on a bunch of parameterized jobs was my last shot, but that just ended up showing a lot of quick "ghost jobs" for devices not active for the current build run.

Any ideas or pointers or good practices you guys think I should follow?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Today, I think I found a robust enough solution despite having been at this for a few days. I added a per-device Jenkinsfile into each software repository and then configured in-line pipelines via the Jenkins GUI that orchestrate calling of these files. This way I can easily get builds either all software for all target devices, all software for one target device or one software for all target devices.